# How can i load shared library in Tcl 8.4 version?

Tags: shared-libraries, tcl

I am working with tcl version 8.4 and I want to use the tcl Thread package, but it is not built-in with version 8.4, so I tried to download and use the package directly. I downloaded the thread2.8.8 package and made the libthread2.8.8.so file. However, there is a code part in the pkgIndex.tcl file that 'load the libthread2.8.8.so' code, but the load command does not exist in version 8.4, causing an error. How can I load shared library in version 8.4?

I have searched for ways to load shared library in tcl version 8.4, but I have not been able to find any solutions, so I am asking for help.

Comment: Are you sure than `load` command doesn’t exists in 8.4, this [command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/load.html) seems to exist.

Comment: For the Thread package to be useful, the Tcl interpreter you load it into needs to have been built with thread support.  If I recall correctly, this was **not** the default for Tcl8.4.  Building with thread support **is** the default for the current release, Tcl 8.6.13.

Answer (score 1):

The `load` command has existed since before 8.0.

The thread package is tricky. It requires that the Tcl build that it loads into be *thread-enabled* for the majority of its functionality; that was not the default build configuration until... 8.5 or 8.6? I forget which. I remember that the key worry for people was the Expect package (which only likes to be used from the main thread even now).

Officially, I do not recommend doing new work on 8.4 now, and haven't done for somewhere on the order of over a decade.

---

You don't mention what the error message is. That *might* guide you to what to fix; Tcl's error messages usually do. However, the errors from `load` are sometimes hard to interpret (some of them come from the underlying OS API for dynamic library loading, and have definitely varying quality and utility). The thread library is unlikely to be the worst in that respect, as it has simple dependencies.

The one thing I'll mention is that if the thread library isn't built to be stubs enabled, it probably needs to be built against the right version of Tcl (the one you're loading into). How closely it needs to match depends on many platform-specific details. One of the advantages of the stubs mechanism is that it handles Tcl's internal language version profiles for you.